# nested loop with jquery image slider

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, loops, slider

I'm using a jquery image slider that, display images 3 by 3. All the images are coming from database. This is my code:

```
<ul class="bxslider">

<?php
    $data = [ my images array];

    for($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) {
?>
        <li>
            <div class="service_images">
            <?php
                $y=0;
                while($y < 3) {
                    if($data[$y] != '') {
                        $imgNew = $data[$y];
            ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $imgNew;?>" alt="" />
            <?php
                    }
                    $y++;
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
```

And this code is displaying just 1 image, and it's repeating.
plz help me guys. thanks.

Comment: give the output of `$data`

Comment: please share the generated html

Comment: $data is the image array. ($data = img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got this working... displayed 3x3 and you can check source... each img src increments by one each time. so that will give you 3 X 3.

heres my code, just need to adapt it a little (remove the array I made and replace it with yours.

```
<?php
$datas = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$y=0;
echo "<li>";
    foreach ($datas as $data)
        {
         if($data != "")
            {
               $y++;
               echo "<img src=" . $data . " alt='' />";

               if($y % 3  == 0)
                   {
                    if($y < count($datas))
                        {
                             echo"</li>";
                             echo "<li>";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                             echo"</li>";   
                        }

                   }

             }

        }
?>
</ul>
```

if you need any help, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ul class="bxslider">

<?php
    $data = [ my images array];

    for($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) {
?>
    <li>
        <div class="service_images">
        <?php
            if($data[$x] != '') {
                $imgNew = $data[$x];
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imgNew;?>" alt="" />
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is going to be show all images in one frame, I need only 3 images to be show in a frame. I mean 3 by 3. any way thanks for the response!

Comment: In that case, add this code,

declare $y = 1 before for loop

       <?php
        
        if($y <= 3) {
          if($data[$x] != '') {
                $imgNew = $data[$x];
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imgNew;?>" alt="" />
        <?php
            $y++;
            }
          }
        ?>